# bash script: how to run find command and variables

Tags: bash

I'm new to it. x can not be recognized from above statement. What is the problem?

```
x = find . -name "*.java" | wc -l
echo $x
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be

```
x=$(find . -name "*.java" | wc -l)
```

(Note that there is no space around the `=` sign)

---

To answer your question, the problem is

1. the space after `x` causes the shell to try to execute the command `x` which probably does not exist
2. you want the **result** of the command to be stored in `x`, so you need to *execute* the command (hence the `$(...)`)

Comment: @sweet You probably inserted a space before `=`.

Answer (score 1):

This should also work:

```
x=`find . -name "*.java" | wc -l`
```

Comment: For no particular reason (maybe because it's one fewer character?) I prefer this notation. And it's a bit more stack-overflowey - the same backticks we use in markdown.